# Why does the rbx register not affect the value of the al register?

Tags: cpu-registers

I am trying to teach my self x86-84 assembly language programming, and am using a pdf called "x86-84 Assembly Language Programming with Ubuntu". There is one part that is talking about widening conversions and it gives this example:

```
mov al, 50
mov rbx, 0
mov bl, al
```

According to the author. the 64-bit rbx register now has a value of 50, but how come the instruction "mov rbx, 0" does not set the value of the whole register to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
first line: al=50
second line: rbx=0
third line: set the lowest byte of rbx register to 50
result: rbx=50, as well as bx=50 and bl=50
```

I found nice picture that explains how the registers are shared:

[image: register structure]

By altering `ah`, or `al` registers you alter also AX, EAX and RAX registers

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at code and thought RAX and RBX registers were the same thing, lol